# Откуда берется этот отступ над шапкой и как пофиксить?

Tags: html, css

При загружении страницы над шапкой появляется неизвестный мне отступ `15-20рх`. Хотя в `body` прописаны `padding` и `margin` со значением `0`. Если прописать `margin: -20px` то отступ пропадет, но это ведь не выход. Как с этим бороться?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "PT Sans Narrow", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 24px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #000;
  background-image: url(img/index/background.jpg);
  background-position: top center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <header class="main_header">
    <nav class="main_navigation">
      <ul class="site_navigation">
        <li> <a href="info.html">Информация</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="news.html">Новости</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="price.html">Прайс-лист</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="shop.html">Магазин</a> </li>
        <li> <a href="contacts.html">Контакты</a> </li>
      </ul>

      <ul>
        <li class="login_link"> <a class="login_link" href="login.html">Вход</a> </li>
      </ul>

      <a class="main_header_logo">
        <img src="img/index/index-logo.svg" width="368" height="153" alt="Логотип">
      </a>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>
```

Comment: Проверил Ваш код, у меня отступов нету

Comment: Возможно это ошибка в моем браузере? Я уже выяснил, что проблема с обнулением body. Если прописать *{margin: 0;} то оступ сверху не будет. Но сам тег body почему-то обнулятся не хочет

Comment: Попробуйте добавить `body {margin: 0 !important;}`

Comment: @CbIPoK2513
Не помогло(
Открыл файл с компьтера, там отступов не показывает. Возможно проблема кроется в параметрах ноутбука, не подскажите?

Comment: Еще какие-то стили применяете? reset.css какой-нибудь?

Comment: Возможно, кому-то пригодится инфа. Проблему я качественно не устранил но нашел 3 уловки, которые могут помочь: обнулить весь css; прописать минусовой margin; прописать такой же background-color для html какой и у фашей шапки